# FileReader/Scanner reading file name rather than contents of .txt file

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a Huffman algorithm that takes in characters from a .txt file. The txt file contains a paragraph of text. Right now when I run the program like so

```
java HuffmanCode large.txt
```

it produces output, but what it evaluated was the name of the file, "large.txt", rather than the text inside the file large.txt. How do I get it to read the contents instead?? Thanks for your help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        String inputFileName = args[0];
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

        int[] charFreqs = new int[256];
        // read each character and record the frequencies
        for (char c : inputFileName.toCharArray())
            charFreqs[c]++;

        // build tree
        HuffmanTree tree = buildTree(charFreqs);

        // print out results
        System.out.println("SYMBOL\tWEIGHT\tHUFFMAN CODE");
        printCodes(tree, new StringBuffer());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahem - `inputFileName.toCharArray()`. Your IDEs unused warnings should have clued you into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close - you're just iterating over `inputFileName.toCharArray()`, which is giving you the characters in the file name. You need to read characters from your `in` variable (which will give you the file contents) instead, eg:

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    char[] line = in.nextLine().toCharArray();
    for (char c : line)
        charFreqs[c]++;
}
```

Note this will probably discard any newline characters in the file, so if you want to count them you'll probably have to do it manually. Or switch to reading raw `char[]`s from the `FileReader` you already have, which is probably a better approach than above (you want raw character data, not "text" data, which is what `Scanner` operates on).

Comment: Thank you so much! That was perfect. So I am right to say that I have the option between reading by line or reading by char?

Comment: `InputStream` and friends read _bytes_. `Reader` and friends read characters. Do not confuse the two. And certainly don’t confuse `byte` and `char` - whilst it may seem that you can simply cast ; this is a very bad idea if reading from a file.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh good point, I was thinking in C mode. I've updated the answer to reflect.